# Error from server (NotFound): persistentvolumeclaims "jenkins-pv-claim" not found

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

My PVC is in lost state so I tried to delete the PVC but I am getting the PVC not found error how to clear this issue
please find the below screen shots.
[pvc listed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyDtZ.png)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vd3VR.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the screeshots that you have shared, I could see your PVC is in `jenkins` namespace. But you are running `kubectl delete pvc jenkins-pv-claim` command in `default` namespace.

To resolve this error, you have to run `kubectl` command in `jenkins` namespace

```
kubectl delete pvc jenkins-pv-claim -n jenkins
```

Comment: thanks for the response yes its working

Comment: Could you Please, Accept the solution.

Comment: sorry  its done  Thank you once again